# Crystal Reports - Adding Arabic and English in the same field

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to add a paragraph in English and another in Arabic **in the same cell**, is there a way to set the Horizontal Alignment and the Reading Order with different values? 
can I use a delimiter to split them and set their alignment and reading order?

Comment: No, a single field cannot have multiple alignments or reading orders. Why can't you just use two fields?

Comment: I can't use two fields because I rely on the (Can Grow) property to add a dynamic number of paragraphs, adding multiple fields would cause blanking issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding a split formula to adding specific alignment for each paragraph won't solve the issue. 
Referring to crystal reports documentation, one field can't have multiple alignments or reading orders.

Answer (score 0):

Take text field add english then add delimiter then arabic..

Place the field on design and enable can grow property

Comment: That would make both English and Arabic in the same left horizontal alignment; the Arabic should be right aligned.

Comment: Can you post screenshot